# What cmd sencha template does?

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

I'm reading the sencha cmd [docs](https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/7.2.0/guides/cli_reference.html#cli_reference_-_sencha_template) about template command. The are no relevant information about it:

[image]

My question is what are templates? How this can be useful to build applications?

Answer (score 0):

Documentation about it is here https://docs.sencha.com/architect/4.2/guides/extending_architect/creating_app_templates.html

> Typically, you would create a project that contains only the code that you want used in all projects that are based on this app template.
> A good use for a custom app template would be to create login functionality that can be used in all projects that require the user to log into the company site.

An application can be generated using a created template like this:

sencha --sdk-path `SDK_PATH` generate app --starter `TEMPLATE_SOURCE` `APPLICATION_NAME` `APPLICATION_PATH`

used generate app options:

- --starter, -s - Overrides the default Starter App template directory
- --template, -te - The name of the template to use

used sencha options:

- --sdk-path, -sd - The location of the SDK to use for non-app commands